# Load CCSprite Image from URL - CocosSharp + Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, ccsprite

I am working on Xamarin.Forms + CocosSharp Application. Here I want to load an image from an URL in cocoassharp using CCSprite. How can I achieve this? Normal CCSprite image is created like: var sprite = new CCSprite("image.png");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use async for stream and Read. I just did testing in place where that was not convenient but you should use async versions.

```
        var webClient = new HttpClient();
        var imageStream = webClient.GetStreamAsync(new Uri("https://xamarin.com/content/images/pages/forms/example-app.png")).Result;
        byte[] imageBytes = new byte[imageStream.Length];
        int read=0;
        do
        {
            read += imageStream.Read(imageBytes, read, imageBytes.Length- read);
        } while (read< imageBytes.Length);
        CCTexture2D texture = new CCTexture2D(imageBytes);
        var sprite = new CCSprite(texture);
```

[image]